# Reading Excel Files In PHP without third party libraries

Tags: php, excel, file

How do I Read & Process Excel files using PHP?

There are lot of such questions already posted but all the answers contain link to some third party libraries such as PHPExcel.

Is there any way to Read Excel files **without using any such libraries** and directly using PHP?

Comment: sure, but good luck parsing the contents. .xls is a Compound-OLE file, and even Bill Gates can't understand it. .xlsx is easier - it's a zip file of xml, style sheets, etc... b

Comment: Is reading xlsx easy?

Comment: You can read and parse any file.. They're just bytes, but you must know the structure of the file. Learn the structure, or use a library from someone who did.

Comment: by whose standards? READING data is ALWAYS easy. **INTERPRETING** it is the hard part.

Comment: Yeah it's not just about reading but actually interpreting the data and that's what i want to do

Comment: I don't know if ODBC drivers count as third-party library but it's the only other option (and not a reliable one anyway).